# Why I can't select the last letter when I set the font tracking

Tags: java, swing, fonts, selection

When I set the font tracking I can't select the last letter with the mouse. Please see this example:

```
 public class TrackingTest extends JFrame {

        public TrackingTest(String text) {
            addContent(text);
        }

        private void addContent(String text) {
            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            Map att = new HashMap();
            att.put(TextAttribute.SIZE, 20);
            att.put(TextAttribute.FAMILY, "Arial");
            att.put(TextAttribute.TRACKING, 1.0f);
            Font font = Font.getFont(att);
            field.setFont(font);
            field.setText(text);
            getContentPane().add(field);

        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    final TrackingTest test = new TrackingTest("abcdeas");
                            test.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    test.pack();
                    test.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well on my side, I can easily select all letters from either left or right. This is my java version `C:\Mine\java\bin>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_51`

Comment: Yes, but only the last letter no chance. The caret position is also wrong. Tested with java version: 1.6.0_21; 1.7.0_02

Comment: Are you seeing something different to [this behavior](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Qi4.gif) (as seen on 1.7.0_25)?

Comment: Did you select with keys or mouse? I tested also with 1.7.0_11 and I can't select the last character with mouse

Comment: @user2358141: Just drag the mouse, I am able to select everythingy. What is your OS, if you using Windows 8/Windows 8.1/Windows 10, then first try to bring your Java application to the middle of the screen, and then try it/

Comment: My OS is Windows 7. Selecting all wasn't my problem, I want select the last letter with mouse. And an other thing I can't see the caret before the last letter when I click on.

Comment: @user2358141: Do one thingy, just write this line `test.setLocationByPlatform ( true );` after `test.pack()`, but before `test.setVisible ( true )` and then try to select with mouse, you be able to select everythingy in one go. At the corners of the desktop, you might be having some glitch. Try this and let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the help bu it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2358141: Please have a look at this, [I selected with mouse and copied the content](http://i.imgur.com/tFHkgTv.gifv). For the rest, You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)